# Keithley Test Script Builder (LUA): Issue with appending relative time stamp to output file along with channel data

Tags: lua, timestamp, buffer

First time post here, I am new to LUA and have some issues:

I am trying to create a script the outputs the channels from a Keithley Digital Multi-meter to a usb stick . I am able to do this however I would like to have relative time in a readable format stitch to each channel . Using the keithley manual I used the buffer.saveappend syntax to do this but I end up with a TSP run time error
The error received is the following.

TSP>-286, TSP Runtime error: Cannot modify this read-only item.
I have attached my script below:

```lua
    (1) Keithley DMM6500
    (2) Vrpobe (DUT)
    (3) Keithley Break Out Board
          
    ]]--
    --------------------------
    --Thermal Couple Reading
    --Reset the instrument 
    reset()
    --settimezone("8", "1", "3.3.0/02", "11.2.0/02")
    --systemTime = os.time({year = 2022, month = 5, day = 04, hour = 13, min = 49})
    --settime(systemTime)
    --Establish variables to make a measurement every 60 seconds 1440 times (24 hours).
    local scanCnt = 8 * 2 --480 minutes = 8 hours
    local chanCnt = 10
    local totalRdgs = scanCnt * chanCnt
    --Empty the buffer and set it to the capacity calculated by totalRdgs.
    defbuffer1.clear()
    defbuffer1.capacity = totalRdgs
    mybuffer1=dmm.makebuffer(30000, buffer.STYLE_FULL)
    mybuffer1.collecttimestamps = 0
    mybuffer1.collectsourcevalues = 0
    mybuffer1.appendmode = 1
    -- Set up the channels to measure voltage and temperature
    channel.setdmm("2", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_FUNCTION, dmm.FUNC_AC_VOLTAGE)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_FUNCTION, dmm.FUNC_TEMPERATURE)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_UNIT, dmm.UNIT_CELSIUS)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_NPLC, 1)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_DIGITS, dmm.DIGITS_5_5)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_TRANSDUCER, dmm.TRANS_THERMOCOUPLE)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_THERMOCOUPLE, dmm.THERMOCOUPLE_K)
    channel.setdmm("3", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_REF_JUNCTION, dmm.REFJUNCT_EXTERNAL)
    channel.setdmm("4:10", dmm.ATTR_MEAS_FUNCTION, dmm.FUNC_RESISTANCE)
    channel.setlabel("3", "Thermocouple")
    channel.setlabel("2", "SigIn")
    channel.setlabel("4", "Ch4")
    channel.setlabel("5", "Ch5")
    channel.setlabel("6", "Ch6")
    channel.setlabel("7", "Ch7")
    channel.setlabel("8", "Ch8")
    channel.setlabel("9", "Ch9")
    channel.setlabel("10", "Ch10")
    -- Set up the scan; channel 3 is first available  on a 2001-TCSCAN card.
    scan.create("2,3,4:10")
    scan.scancount = scanCnt
    -- Set the amount of time for each scan.
    scan.scaninterval =5.0
    -- Write the data to a USB flash drive at the end of the scan.
    --dmm.appendbuffer("bufferVar","/usb1/Dump_Data.csv", buffer.SAVE_FORMAT_TIME)
    --dmm.appendbuffer("debuffer1","/usb1/Dump_Data.csv", buffer.SAVE_FORMAT_TIME)
    buffer.saveappend(mybuffer1, "/usb1/Dump_Data.csv", buffer.SAVE_RELATIVE_TIME)
    scan.export("/usb1/Dump_Data.csv", scan.WRITE_AFTER_SCAN, buffer.COL_CSV_CHAN_COLS)
    trigger.model.initiate()
    waitcomplete()
    -- Get the data.
    printbuffer(l, defbuffer1.n, defbuffer1, mybuffer1)
```

Comment: You forgot to say the error

Comment: @emoney3 you mentioned a `TSP run time error` can be provide the full text of that error?

Comment: Hi ! Sorry about that, here is the error.TSP>-286, TSP Runtime error: Cannot modify this read-only item.

Comment: TSP>-286, TSP Runtime error: Cannot modify this read-only item.